# The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (forkpty(3) failed.)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

As the title says I'm having trouble launching the terminal whenever I connect in a remote server. I'm using Mac, it was only working fine yesterday.
Maybe someone can help me.
Thanks!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFeVO.png]